# How to simplify a discord bot remote tool

Tags: python

After a bit of struggling I've come up with the code

```py
import discord
import os
import subprocess as sub
import psutil

client = discord.Client()

my_path = os.getcwd()
program_instance = False
currently_installed = os.path.isdir("web-application")

def run_command(command):
    value = sub.Popen(command, stdout = sub.PIPE, stderr = sub.PIPE)
    return value.communicate()
    
def kill():
    global program_instance
    if not program_instance:
        return "Program instance not initiated";
    process = psutil.Process(program_instance.pid)
    for proc in process.children(recursive = True):
        proc.kill()
    process.kill()
    program_instance = False
    return "Instance Killed"

def delete_if_exists():
    global currently_installed
    kill()
    if currently_installed:
        os.system("rmdir /S /Q web-application")
        while currently_installed:
            currently_installed = os.path.isdir("web-application")


def download_from_git():
    #pull from git
    global currently_installed
    kill()
    delete_if_exists()
    instance = sub.Popen("git clone LINKTOWEBAPPLICATION")
    instance.communicate()
    currently_installed = True
    return "Successfully downloaded"
    
def run(download = False):
    global program_instance
    folders = run_command("dir")
    if not currently_installed or download:
        download_from_git()
    kill()
    path = my_path+"\\web-application"
    #installing values in pipenv
    install_command_instance = sub.Popen("pipenv install", cwd = path)
    install_command_instance.communicate()
    
    program_instance = sub.Popen("pipenv run app.py", cwd = path)
    return "App Running"

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Gitty woke")



@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot or not message.channel.id == MYDISCORDUSERID:
        return;
    command = message.content

    checker = lambda command_name: command == command_name

    if checker("run"):
        await message.channel.send(run())

    if checker("kill"):
        await message.channel.send(kill())

    if checker("download"):
        await message.channel.send(download_from_git())

    if checker("run download"):
        await message.channel.send(run(download = True))

    if checker("ping"):
        currently_installed = os.path.isdir("web-application")
        await message.channel.send("Running:" + f"\n{program_instance=}, {currently_installed=}")
        
with open(".key", "r") as key:
    client.run(key.read())
```

The biggest problem with this code was killing running processes. I just wanted to know if there are any easier ways to do this. And if I made any choices which are over complicated.

Edit:
This bot is built to pull a repo from GitHub which contains a web-application that needs to be run. The reason I have to kill the application is so I can download a new version and rerun the code (as multiple instances of the website would be bad). The issue is that when the website is running I also have to be able to send the bot commands and thus have to run it as a separate instance so that the bot doesn't get "clogged" up running the site and can still take inputs

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the nature and purpose of the process.

For example, you might schedule your process as a coroutine, and cancel its execution with `Future.cancel`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future.cancel

Your process killing method is aggressive and quite risky, some more context around why you're cancelling processes and the nature of the processes would be useful for providing answers.